# build Go with gccgo - fork/exec no such file or directory

Tags: gcc, go, compilation, gccgo

I am trying to run a simple helloworld.go on RHEL 6.8.

```
% cat helloworld.go 
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

The GC compiler works ok

```
%  go build -compiler gccgo helloworld.go 
go build command-line-arguments: : fork/exec : no such file or directory
```

For some reason, instead, I need to compile with gccgo, but could never get it to compile. Let alone to eventually compile it statically.

```
% go build -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags '-static' helloworld.go
go build command-line-arguments: : fork/exec : no such file or directory
% go build -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags '-static-libgo' helloworld.go
go build command-line-arguments: : fork/exec : no such file or directory


% go version 
go version go1.7 linux/amd64
% gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)
```

Insights on what the problem is would be appreciated?

Comment: The `go` tool is trying to exec something which isn't there. Try using the `-x` to see if you can tell what is being called.

Comment: `go build -compiler gccgo -gccgoflags '-static' -x helloworld.go
WORK=/tmp/go-build267938128`
`mkdir -p $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/`
`mkdir -p $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/exe/`
`cd /root/tmp`
`"" -I $WORK -c -g -m64 -fgo-relative-import-path=_/root/tmp -o $WORK/command-line-arguments/_obj/_go_.o -static ./helloworld.go
go build command-line-arguments: : fork/exec : no such file or directory`

Comment: Any insight from these? @JimB (thanks and sorry for the poor formatting)

Comment: Situation should be improved by now: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19628.

Answer (score -1):

You should install gccgo compiler first. On my Fedora 26 desktop, run `dnf install gcc-go` to install.

`$ which gccgo
/usr/bin/gccgo
go build --compiler gccgo -x
WORK=/tmp/go-build848309745
mkdir -p $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/exe/
cd /home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello
/usr/bin/gccgo -I $WORK -c -g -m64 -fgo-relative-import-path=_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello -o $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/_go_.o ./helloworld.go
ar rc $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/libhello.a $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/_go_.o
cd .
/usr/bin/gccgo -o $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/exe/a.out $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/_go_.o -Wl,-( -m64 -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,-)
cp $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/exe/a.out hello`

If you need to link static, package glibc-static and libgo-static are required to be installed too. After installed them, compile using gccgo and link statically by

`$ go build -compiler gccgo -x --gccgoflags "-static" 
WORK=/tmp/go-build815863722
mkdir -p $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/exe/
cd /home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello
/usr/bin/gccgo -I $WORK -c -g -m64 -fgo-relative-import-path=_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello -o $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/_go_.o -static ./helloworld.go
ar rc $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/libhello.a $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/_go_.o
cd .
/usr/bin/gccgo -o $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/exe/a.out $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/_go_.o -Wl,-( -m64 -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,-) -static
cp $WORK/_/home/sam/sandbox/go/src/hello/_obj/exe/a.out hello`